# Customizing the slider form shopping cart in viewcart.tpl

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, whmcs

I hope some of you are familiar with WHMCS and smarty template language so you can help me. The problem I am having is with viewcart.tpl page of the slider order form template. I want to hide the shopping cart and the complete  order button on this page when you first enter this page. I want to add a continue button that loops back to the same page. When the page loops back to itself you be able to then see the cart and complete order button and the continue button will be hidden. I want the continue button to only work if the order form fields are filled out.

Here is the code of that page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/orderforms/{$carttpl}/style.css" />

<script language="javascript">var statesTab=10;</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/orderforms/{$carttpl}/js/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jscript/statesdropdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jscript/pwstrength.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jscript/creditcard.js"></script>



{literal}<script language="javascript">

function removeItem(type,num) {

    var response = confirm("{/literal}{$LANG.cartremoveitemconfirm}{literal}");

    if (response) {

        window.location = 'cart.php?a=remove&r='+type+'&i='+num;

    }

}

function emptyCart(type,num) {

    var response = confirm("{/literal}{$LANG.cartemptyconfirm}{literal}");

    if (response) {

        window.location = 'cart.php?a=empty';

    }

}

</script>{/literal}

<script>

var langPasswordStrength = "{$LANG.passwordstrength}";

var langPasswordWeak = "{$LANG.weak}";

var langPasswordModerate = "{$LANG.moderate}";

var langPasswordStrong = "{$LANG.strong}";

</script>



<div id="order-slider">



<h1>{$LANG.cartreviewcheckout}</h1>



{if $errormessage}<div class="errorbox" style="display:block;">{$errormessage|replace:'<li>':' &nbsp;#&nbsp; '} &nbsp;#&nbsp; </div>{elseif $promotioncode && $rawdiscount eq "0.00"}<div class="errorbox" style="display:block;">{$LANG.promoappliedbutnodiscount}</div>{/if}



{if $bundlewarnings}

<div class="cartwarningbox">

<strong>{$LANG.bundlereqsnotmet}</strong><br />

{foreach from=$bundlewarnings item=warning}

{$warning}<br />

{/foreach}

</div>

{/if}



{if !$loggedin && $currencies}

<div class="clear"></div>
{
else}

<br />

{/if}



<form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?a=view">



<table class="cart" cellspacing="1">

<tr class="textcenter"><th width="60%">{$LANG.orderdesc}</th><th width="40%">{$LANG.orderprice}</th></tr>



{foreach key=num item=product from=$products}

<tr class="carttableproduct"><td>

<strong><em>{$product.productinfo.groupname}</em> - {$product.productinfo.name}</strong>{if $product.domain} ({$product.domain}){/if}<br />

{if $product.configoptions}

{foreach key=confnum item=configoption from=$product.configoptions}&nbsp;&raquo; {$configoption.name}: {if $configoption.type eq 1 || $configoption.type eq 2}{$configoption.option}{elseif $configoption.type eq 3}{if $configoption.qty}{$LANG.yes}{else}{$LANG.no}{/if}{elseif $configoption.type eq 4}{$configoption.qty} x {$configoption.option}{/if}<br />{/foreach}

{/if}

<a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?a=confproduct&i={$num}" class="cartedit">[{$LANG.carteditproductconfig}]</a> <a href="#" onclick="removeItem('p','{$num}');return false" class="cartremove">[{$LANG.cartremove}]</a>

{if $product.allowqty}

<br /><br />

<div align="right">{$LANG.cartqtyenterquantity} <input type="text" name="qty[{$num}]" size="3" value="{$product.qty}" /> <input type="submit" value="{$LANG.cartqtyupdate}" /></div>

{/if}

</td><td class="textcenter"><strong>{$product.pricingtext}{if $product.proratadate}<br />({$LANG.orderprorata} {$product.proratadate}){/if}</strong></td></tr>

{foreach key=addonnum item=addon from=$product.addons}

<tr class="carttableproduct"><td><strong>{$LANG.orderaddon}</strong> - {$addon.name}</td><td class="textcenter"><strong>{$addon.pricingtext}</strong></td></tr>

{/foreach}

{/foreach}



{foreach key=num item=addon from=$addons}

<tr class="carttableproduct"><td>

<strong>{$addon.name}</strong><br />

{$addon.productname}{if $addon.domainname} - {$addon.domainname}<br />{/if}

<a href="#" onclick="removeItem('a','{$num}');return false" class="cartremove">[{$LANG.cartremove}]</a>

</td><td class="textcenter"><strong>{$addon.pricingtext}</strong></td></tr>

{/foreach}



{foreach key=num item=domain from=$domains}

<tr class="carttableproduct"><td>

<strong>{if $domain.type eq "register"}{$LANG.orderdomainregistration}{else}{$LANG.orderdomaintransfer}{/if}</strong> - {$domain.domain} - {$domain.regperiod} {$LANG.orderyears}<br />

{if $domain.dnsmanagement}&nbsp;&raquo; {$LANG.domaindnsmanagement}<br />{/if}

{if $domain.emailforwarding}&nbsp;&raquo; {$LANG.domainemailforwarding}<br />{/if}

{if $domain.idprotection}&nbsp;&raquo; {$LANG.domainidprotection}<br />{/if}

<a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?a=confdomains" class="cartedit">[{$LANG.cartconfigdomainextras}]</a> <a href="#" onclick="removeItem('d','{$num}');return false" class="cartremove">[{$LANG.cartremove}]</a>

</td><td class="textcenter"><strong>{$domain.price}</strong></td></tr>

{/foreach}



{foreach key=num item=domain from=$renewals}

<tr class="carttableproduct"><td>

<strong>{$LANG.domainrenewal}</strong> - {$domain.domain} - {$domain.regperiod} {$LANG.orderyears}<br />

{if $domain.dnsmanagement}&nbsp;&raquo; {$LANG.domaindnsmanagement}<br />{/if}

{if $domain.emailforwarding}&nbsp;&raquo; {$LANG.domainemailforwarding}<br />{/if}

{if $domain.idprotection}&nbsp;&raquo; {$LANG.domainidprotection}<br />{/if}

<a href="#" onclick="removeItem('r','{$num}');return false" class="cartremove">[{$LANG.cartremove}]</a>

</td><td class="textcenter"><strong>{$domain.price}</strong></td></tr>

{/foreach}



{if $cartitems==0}

<tr class="clientareatableactive"><td colspan="2" class="textcenter">

<br />

{$LANG.cartempty}

<br /><br />

</td></tr>

{/if}



<tr class="subtotal"><td class="textright">{$LANG.ordersubtotal}: &nbsp;</td><td class="textcenter">{$subtotal}</td></tr>

{if $promotioncode}

<tr class="promotion"><td class="textright">{$promotiondescription}: &nbsp;</td><td class="textcenter">{$discount}</td></tr>

{/if}

{if $taxrate}

<tr class="subtotal"><td class="textright">{$taxname} @ {$taxrate}%: &nbsp;</td><td class="textcenter">{$taxtotal}</td></tr>

{/if}

{if $taxrate2}
<tr class="subtotal"><td class="textright">{$taxname2} @ {$taxrate2}%: &nbsp;</td><td class="textcenter">{$taxtotal2}</td></tr>

{/if}

<tr class="total"><td class="textright">{$LANG.ordertotalduetoday}: &nbsp;</td><td class="textcenter">{$total}</td></tr>

{if $totalrecurringmonthly || $totalrecurringquarterly || $totalrecurringsemiannually || $totalrecurringannually || $totalrecurringbiennially || $totalrecurringtriennially}

<tr class="recurring"><td class="textright">{$LANG.ordertotalrecurring}: &nbsp;</td><td class="textcenter">

{if $totalrecurringmonthly}{$totalrecurringmonthly} {$LANG.orderpaymenttermmonthly}<br />{/if}

{if $totalrecurringquarterly}{$totalrecurringquarterly} {$LANG.orderpaymenttermquarterly}<br />{/if}

{if $totalrecurringsemiannually}{$totalrecurringsemiannually} {$LANG.orderpaymenttermsemiannually}<br />{/if}

{if $totalrecurringannually}{$totalrecurringannually} {$LANG.orderpaymenttermannually}<br />{/if}

{if $totalrecurringbiennially}{$totalrecurringbiennially} {$LANG.orderpaymenttermbiennially}<br />{/if}

{if $totalrecurringtriennially}{$totalrecurringtriennially} {$LANG.orderpaymenttermtriennially}<br />{/if}

</td></tr>

{/if}

</table>



</form>



<div class="cartbuttons"><input type="button" value="{$LANG.emptycart}" onclick="emptyCart();return false" /> <input type="button" value="{$LANG.continueshopping}" onclick="window.location='cart.php'" /></div>



{foreach from=$gatewaysoutput item=gatewayoutput}

<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="cartbuttons">{$gatewayoutput}</div>

{/foreach}



{if $cartitems!=0}



<form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?a=checkout" id="mainfrm">

<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />

<input type="hidden" name="custtype" id="custtype" value="{$custtype}" />



<br /><br />



<h2>{$LANG.yourdetails}</h2>



<div style="float:left;width:20px;">&nbsp;</div><div class="signuptype{if !$loggedin && $custtype neq "existing"} active{/if}"{if !$loggedin} id="newcust"{/if}>{$LANG.newcustomer}</div><div class="signuptype{if $custtype eq "existing" && !$loggedin || $loggedin} active{/if}" id="existingcust">{$LANG.existingcustomer}</div>

<div class="clear"></div>



<div class="signupfields{if $custtype eq "existing" && !$loggedin}{else} hidden{/if}" id="loginfrm">

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="configtable">

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaemail}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="loginemail" size="40" /></td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareapassword}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="password" name="loginpw" size="25" /></td></tr>

</table>

</div>
<div class="signupfields{if $custtype eq "existing" && !$loggedin} hidden{/if}" id="signupfrm">

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="configtable">

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareafirstname}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.firstname}{else}<input type="text" name="firstname" tabindex="1" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.firstname}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaaddress1}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.address1}{else}<input type="text" name="address1" tabindex="7" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.address1}" />{/if}</td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientarealastname}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.lastname}{else}<input type="text" name="lastname" tabindex="2" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.lastname}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaaddress2}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.address2}{else}<input type="text" name="address2" tabindex="8" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.address2}" />{/if}</td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacompanyname}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.companyname}{else}<input type="text" name="companyname" tabindex="3" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.companyname}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacity}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.city}{else}<input type="text" name="city" tabindex="9" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.city}" />{/if}</td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaemail}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.email}{else}<input type="text" name="email" tabindex="4" style="width:90%;" value="{$clientsdetails.email}" />{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareastate}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.state}{else}<input type="text" name="state" tabindex="10" style="width:80%;" value="{$clientsdetails.state}" />{/if}</td></tr>

<tr>{if !$loggedin}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareapassword}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="password" name="password" tabindex="5" id="newpw" size="20" value="{$password}" /></td>{else}<td class="fieldlabel"></td><td class="fieldarea"></td>{/if}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareapostcode}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.postcode}{else}<input type="text" name="postcode" tabindex="11" size="15" value="{$clientsdetails.postcode}" />{/if}</td></tr>

<tr>{if !$loggedin}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaconfirmpassword}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="password" name="password2" tabindex="6" size="20" value="{$password2}" /></td>{else}<td class="fieldlabel"></td><td class="fieldarea"></td>{/if}<td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacountry}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.country}{else}{$clientcountrydropdown|replace:'<select':'<select tabindex="12"'}{/if}</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2" class="fieldarea">{if !$loggedin}<script language="javascript">showStrengthBar();</script>{/if}</td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaphonenumber}</td><td class="fieldarea">{if $loggedin}{$clientsdetails.phonenumber}{else}<input type="text" name="phonenumber" tabindex="13" size="20" value="{$clientsdetails.phonenumber}" />{/if}</td></tr>

{if $customfields || $securityquestions}

{if $securityquestions && !$loggedin}

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareasecurityquestion}</td><td class="fieldarea" colspan="3"><select name="securityqid" tabindex="14">

{foreach key=num item=question from=$securityquestions}

    <option value={$question.id}>{$question.question}</option>

{/foreach}

</select></td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareasecurityanswer}</td><td class="fieldarea" colspan="3"><input type="password" name="securityqans" value="{$securityqans}" tabindex="15" size="30"></td></tr>

{/if}

{foreach key=num item=customfield from=$customfields}

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$customfield.name}</td><td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">{$customfield.input} {$customfield.description}</td></tr>

{/foreach}

{/if}

</table>

</div>



{if $taxenabled && !$loggedin}

<div class="carttaxwarning">{$LANG.carttaxupdateselections} <input type="submit" value="{$LANG.carttaxupdateselectionsupdate}" name="updateonly" /></div>

{/if}



{if $domainsinorder}

<h2>{$LANG.domainregistrantinfo}</h2>

<select name="contact" id="domaincontact" onchange="domaincontactchange()">

<option value="">{$LANG.usedefaultcontact}</option>

{foreach from=$domaincontacts item=domcontact}

<option value="{$domcontact.id}"{if $contact==$domcontact.id} selected{/if}>{$domcontact.name}</option>

{/foreach}

<option value="addingnew"{if $contact eq "addingnew"} selected{/if}>{$LANG.clientareanavaddcontact}...</option>

</select><br /><br />

<div class="signupfields{if $contact neq "addingnew"} hidden{/if}" id="domaincontactfields">

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="configtable">

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareafirstname}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactfirstname" style="width:80%;" value="{$domaincontact.firstname}" /></td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaaddress1}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactaddress1" style="width:80%;" value="{$domaincontact.address1}" /></td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientarealastname}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactlastname" style="width:80%;" value="{$domaincontact.lastname}" /></td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaaddress2}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactaddress2" style="width:80%;" value="{$domaincontact.address2}" /></td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacompanyname}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactcompanyname" style="width:80%;" value="{$domaincontact.companyname}" /></td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacity}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactcity" style="width:80%;" value="{$domaincontact.city}" /></td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaemail}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactemail" style="width:90%;" value="{$domaincontact.email}" /></td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareastate}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactstate" style="width:80%;" value="{$domaincontact.state}" /></td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareaphonenumber}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactphonenumber" size="20" value="{$domaincontact.phonenumber}" /></td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareapostcode}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="domaincontactpostcode" size="15" value="{$domaincontact.postcode}" /></td></tr>

<tr><td class="fieldlabel"></td><td class="fieldarea"></td><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.clientareacountry}</td><td class="fieldarea">{$domaincontactcountrydropdown}</td></tr>

</table>

</div>

{/if}



<div class="checkoutcol1">



<div class="signupfields padded">

<h2>{$LANG.orderpromotioncode}</h2>

{if $promotioncode}{$promotioncode} - {$promotiondescription}<br /><a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?a=removepromo">{$LANG.orderdontusepromo}</a>{else}<input type="text" name="promocode" size="20" value="" /> <input type="submit" name="validatepromo" value="{$LANG.orderpromovalidatebutton}" />{/if}

</div>



{if $shownotesfield}

<div class="signupfields padded">

<h2>{$LANG.ordernotes}</h2>

<textarea name="notes" rows="2" style="width:100%" onFocus="if(this.value=='{$LANG.ordernotesdescription}'){ldelim}this.value='';{rdelim}" onBlur="if (this.value==''){ldelim}this.value='{$LANG.ordernotesdescription}';{rdelim}">{$notes}</textarea>

</div>

{/if}



</div>
<div class="checkoutcol2">



<div class="signupfields padded">
<h2>
{$LANG.orderpaymentmethod}</h2>

{foreach key=num item=gateway from=$gateways}<label><input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="{$gateway.sysname}" onclick="{if $gateway.type eq "CC"}showCCForm(){else}hideCCForm(){/if}"{if $selectedgateway eq $gateway.sysname} checked{/if} />{$gateway.name}</label> {/foreach}



<br /><br />



<div id="ccinputform" class="signupfields{if $selectedgatewaytype neq "CC"} hidden{/if}">

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="configtable">

{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour}<tr><td class="fieldlabel"></td><td class="fieldarea"><label><input type="radio" name="ccinfo" value="useexisting" id="useexisting" onclick="useExistingCC()"{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour} checked{else} disabled{/if} /> {$LANG.creditcarduseexisting}{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour} ({$clientsdetails.cclastfour}){/if}</label><br />

<label><input type="radio" name="ccinfo" value="new" id="new" onclick="enterNewCC()"{if !$clientsdetails.cclastfour || $ccinfo eq "new"} checked{/if} /> {$LANG.creditcardenternewcard}</label></td></tr>{else}<input type="hidden" name="ccinfo" value="new" />{/if}

<tr class="newccinfo"{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour && $ccinfo neq "new"} style="display:none;"{/if}><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.creditcardcardtype}</td><td class="fieldarea"><select name="cctype" id="cctype">

{foreach key=num item=cardtype from=$acceptedcctypes}

<option{if $cctype eq $cardtype} selected{/if}>{$cardtype}</option>

{/foreach}
</select></td></tr>

<tr class="newccinfo"{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour && $ccinfo neq "new"} style="display:none;"{/if}><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.creditcardcardnumber}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="ccnumber" size="30" value="{$ccnumber}" autocomplete="off" /></td></tr>

<tr class="newccinfo"{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour && $ccinfo neq "new"} style="display:none;"{/if}><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.creditcardcardexpires}</td><td class="fieldarea"><select name="ccexpirymonth" id="ccexpirymonth" class="newccinfo">

{foreach from=$months item=month}

<option{if $ccexpirymonth eq $month} selected{/if}>{$month}</option>

{/foreach}</select> / <select name="ccexpiryyear" class="newccinfo">

{foreach from=$expiryyears item=year}

<option{if $ccexpiryyear eq $year} selected{/if}>{$year}</option>

{/foreach}

</select></td></tr>

{if $showccissuestart}

<tr class="newccinfo"{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour && $ccinfo neq "new"} style="display:none;"{/if}><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.creditcardcardstart}</td><td class="fieldarea"><select name="ccstartmonth" id="ccstartmonth" class="newccinfo">

{foreach from=$months item=month}

<option{if $ccstartmonth eq $month} selected{/if}>{$month}</option>

{/foreach}</select> / <select name="ccstartyear" class="newccinfo">

{foreach from=$startyears item=year}

<option{if $ccstartyear eq $year} selected{/if}>{$year}</option>

{/foreach}

</select></td></tr>

<tr class="newccinfo"{if $clientsdetails.cclastfour && $ccinfo neq "new"} style="display:none;"{/if}><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.creditcardcardissuenum}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="ccissuenum" value="{$ccissuenum}" size="5" maxlength="3" /></td></tr>

{/if}

<tr><td class="fieldlabel">{$LANG.creditcardcvvnumber}</td><td class="fieldarea"><input type="text" name="cccvv" id="cccvv" value="{$cccvv}" size="5" autocomplete="off" /> <a href="#" onclick="window.open('images/ccv.gif','','width=280,height=200,scrollbars=no,top=100,left=100');return false">{$LANG.creditcardcvvwhere}</a></td></tr>

{if $shownostore}<tr><td class="fieldlabel"><input type="checkbox" name="nostore" id="nostore" /></td><td><label for="nostore">{$LANG.creditcardnostore}</label></td></tr>{/if}

</table>

</div>



</div>



</div>

<div class="clear"></div>



{if $accepttos}

<div align="center"><label><input type="checkbox" name="accepttos" id="accepttos" /> {$LANG.ordertosagreement} <a href="{$tosurl}" target="_blank">{$LANG.ordertos}</a></label></div>

<br />

{/if}



<div align="center"><input type="submit" value="{$LANG.completeorder}"{if $cartitems==0} disabled{/if} onclick="this.value='{$LANG.pleasewait}'" class="ordernow" /></div>



</form>



{else}



<br /><br />



{/if}



<div class="cartwarningbox"><img src="images/padlock.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" alt="Secure Transaction" /> &nbsp;{$LANG.ordersecure} (<strong>{$ipaddress}</strong>) {$LANG.ordersecure2}</div>



</div>
```

Help would greatly be appreciated. If there is another way or easier way to hide the shopping cart and complete order button until the order form is filled out, could you let me know. I already thought of adding another slider order form template page and moving the cart to that page but unfortunately I don't think you can do that cause of the way WHMCS is set up.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do, is using JavaScript to achieve that. You should use `onchange` or `oninput` method to track changes and to display what you want. Of course JavaScript in browser should be enabled.

Sample working code:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<style type="Text/css">
#mycart, #continue {
    display: none;
}

</style>
<body>

<div id="mycart">My cart</div>

<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" oninput = "check()" onchange = "check()" />

<select name="options" id="options" onchange = "check()">

<option value="0">Select option</option>
<option value="1">option1</option>
<option value="2">option2</option>
</select>

</form>

<div id="continue">Continue</div>

<script>
    function check() {
       var text = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
       var option = document.getElementById("options");
       option = option.options[option.selectedIndex].value 

       if (text != '' && option != 0 ) {
           document.getElementById("mycart").style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById("continue").style.display = 'block';

       }
       else {
           document.getElementById("mycart").style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById("continue").style.display = 'none';           
       }

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you need to adjust code to your needs.

Comment: okay I will try using this code. Can you use the onchange or oninput method to track buttons clicks? Cause I don't want the cart to show until I click the continue button which brings up the same page just without the form.

Comment: @user3381910 Yes, you can then add `onclick="check(); return false;"` only to this button to display cart after click on this button and checking if values are ok.

Comment: There is also a field in the order form I only want to show if a specific product is selected otherwise it will be hidden. Can I use the same method for that as well?

Comment: @user3381910  Yes, you can

Comment: I tried it and I don't know if I did anything wrong but it didn't work. I had to actually add the onclick to the button on the products page which is before the veiwcart.tpl page and it still didn't work. I also took the JavaScript function and put it in the main.js file.

Comment: I put the javascript code up on a fiddle later on so you can view it.